# Cannot use variable of type C.struct_Foo as type package.C.struct_Foo when importing "C" type in two files

Tags: go

Even if I am including the **same** C header file into 2 different go files, I am getting an error as the compiler thinks the types are different. I originally had the header included system-wide (using `<>` without path location) but that didn't work either.

```
// main.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/john-difool/test/lib"
)

//#include "lib/types.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    var p C.Point

    p.x = 0
    p.y = 0
    fmt.Println(lib.CheckPoint(p))
}
```

```
// lib/lib.go

package lib

//#include "types.h"
import "C"

func CheckPoint(pt C.Point) bool {
    return true // TOnotDO
}
```

```
// lib/types.h

typedef struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;
```

This is the error I am getting doing `go build` at the top level:

> cannot use p (type C.struct_Point) as type lib.C.struct_Point in
>   argument to lib.CheckPoint

Comment: This is standard behaviour. The types are not the same, as they are imported in two different Go packages.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty big limitation. What if I need to use some C types in more than one go file? What is your recommendation to make this work?

Comment: You would export `C.Point` from `lib` as a new type: `type Point C.Point`, and `lib`'s functions to accept that type. However, this requires that your C structs have exported field names (i.e. start with an uppercase letter). If they don't, you will have to create wrapper Go structs that copy information to and from the C struct.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/q-oHTRaIlb

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Legacy code has got mostly everything with lowercase fields because that's the way C coders write code. So the trick with type-aliasing won't work. I am going to see if I can "unsafe cast" in the signature of the functions instead and when I have more time write the proper go bindings. That's a real bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: **with lower case C headers**:
you need to define new Setter Methods and
export Point from lib like this, it will work:
working sample:
lib.go file:

```
package lib

/*
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
}  point_t;
*/
import "C"

type Point C.point_t

func (p *Point) SetX(x float32) {
    p.x = C.float(x)
}

func (p *Point) SetY(y float32) {
    p.y = C.float(y)
}

func CheckPoint(pt Point) bool {
    return pt.x == 1 && pt.y == 2
}
```

main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/john-difool/test/lib"
)

func main() {
    var p lib.Point

    p.SetX(1)
    p.SetY(2)
    fmt.Println(lib.CheckPoint(p)) //true
}
```

Old:
export Point from lib like this, it will work:
working sample:
lib.go file:

```
package lib

/*
typedef struct{
    float X;
    float Y;
}  Point_t;
*/
import "C"

type Point C.Point_t

func CheckPoint(pt Point) bool {
    return pt.X == 1 && pt.Y == 2
}
```

main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/john-difool/test/lib"
)

func main() {
    var p lib.Point

    p.X = 1
    p.Y = 2
    fmt.Println(lib.CheckPoint(p)) //true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am using a C library which doesn't have the capitalized fields in the headers. Therefore your assignments in main() don't work. I am still investigating if I can unsafe wrap the structs.

Comment: @john-difool : updated with lower case C headers, you need to define new Setter Methods, like sample code.